# Map property to observable with AngularFirebase / ionic2

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I have a problem to render data that was mapped to an observable.

This is how my code looks:

```js
// ChatService.ts
getChats() {
    return this.authService.getUid().then(uid => {
        let chats = this.af.database.list(`/users/${uid}/chats`);
        return chats;
    });
}

// Chatcomponent.ts
chats: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

this.chatService.getChats()
    .then(chats => {
        this.chats = chats.map(users => {
            return users.map(user => {
                user.info = this.af.database.object(`/users/${user.$key}`)
                return user;
            });
        });
    })
```

```html
//The HTML File
// chat.html
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let chat of chats | async" (click)="openChat(chat.$key)">
  <p>{{chat.$key}}</p>
  <span>{{(chat.info| async).displayName}}</span>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Now when rendering the page, it shows up chat.$key correctly, but chat.info.displayName does not render.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `<span>{{(chat.info| async).displayName}}</span>` why use async again? its not required inside the loop

Comment: Thanks, i did not know that. But changing to {{chat.info.displayName}} makes no difference. The data does still not render.

Comment: what does `console.log(chats)` in `getChats()` print? maybe you are not getting displayname from server side

Comment: the map function works until reaching this line: user.info = this.af.database.object(`/users/${user.key}`). the user.key is available, but it seems that it is not adding the info property.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the html template.

It worked after i changed {{(chat.info | async).displayName}} in to {{(chat?.info | async)?.displayName}}